# Windows Universal App Detect Available Com Ports

Tags: c#, io, serial-port, win-universal-app

I am very new in Windows Universal Application development and want to create app where I can play with IrDA devices.
I have already worked with com ports using `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`
What is equivalent code of `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()` in Windows Universal App.
What other factors I need to be consider while working with SerialPort communication.

I have tried following code:

Added following Capabilities in Package.aapxmanifest

```
 <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort"/>
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

I have written following code on button click event

```
 string selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
            DeviceInformationCollection deviceInformation =
                     await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
```

selector value after running code:

```
System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:="{86E0D1E0-8089-11D0-9CE4-08003E301F73}" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True
```

deviceInformation value returns following error:

[image]

Comment: Probably this one : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/SerialSample.htm

Comment: Or this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32024009/windows-uwp-windows-devices-serialcommunication-serialdevice-not-working

Comment: I think you're doing everything right. What are your running your app on, Raspberry Pi?