# Reading from a serial port in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, serial-port

Using `Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication`, how could I read data from a serial port?

I initialize the `SerialDevice` class, instantiate `DataReader` and `DataWriter` classes using the adequate streams of the device. I can write to the device (device does what it is intended) as

```
        byte[] vs = {'b','t'};
        _dataWriter.WriteBytes(vs);
        await _dataWriter.StoreAsync();
```

But I can't read the response of the device. The device definitely responds, it is specified in the device protocol (`CashCode` protocol). I communicated with the device using a.NET Framework app perfectly.

I try to read in multiple ways, for instance I tried this:

```
            uint i = await _dataReader.LoadAsync(BufferSize);
            if (i > 0)
                await _dataReader.LoadAsync(i);
            _dataReader.ReadBytes(res);
```

The problem is also that I don't know the exact `BufferSize`. This never reads anything.

I am making a `UWP` (, it has to be) app. I made a .NET framework app which works as intended, but it turns out that I can't use it in this project. The serial device is `Suzo Happ Bill-to-Bill unit`. Maybe this issue is connected with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256707/problems-with-serial-device-communication-in-uwp).

Comment: How did you set [InputStreamOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader#Windows_Storage_Streams_DataReader_InputStreamOptions)? The size of the buffer shouldn't really matter (you just read it in a loop). Also note you can use .NET Stream APIs if you prefer.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Cloud the loop be executed in a separate thread? Could you show me an example? I didn't set the InputStreamOptions in any way explicitly.

Comment: Does [the official Serial sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SerialArduino) help?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Thank you for googling it for me. I've found a similar official project and done everything, just not the cancellation token and lock things. I doubt that the problem lies there, but I will try it.

Comment: I use Bing :-) but cancellation is not required. If you still have problems you will need to post a minimal reproduction. And it might be hard to help since it requires specific hardware.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT That is cool too :) I didn't solve the problem, but I will try something else tomorrow... What do you mean by "minimal reproduction"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166871/discussion-between-shocky2-and-peter-torr-msft).

Comment: Sigh, I wish the discussion didn't continue in chat.

Comment: @FilipeMadureira Sadly, the problem wasn't solved back then. We solved the problem by writing another application that used .NET Framework which communicated with our .NET Core application through a web socket.